# SQLAlchemy - Referencing from a table multiple times to another table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and as the title suggests, I am having a hard time with referencing a table multiple times to another table. I'm trying to make a schedules table that includes a 'created_by' and 'created_for' field which can sometimes be different. What I planned to do was to use the user.id as a foreign key for both but it shows the error

Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Here's my code which may help

```
class UserModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    position = Column(String)
    department = Column(String)
    contact_num = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    privilege = Column(Integer)
    password = Column(String)
    schedule = relationship("ScheduleModel", back_populates= "created_for", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    created_schedule = relationship("ScheduleModel", back_populates= "created_by")


class ScheduleModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True, index= True)
    schedule_name = Column(String)
    start_date = Column(DateTime)
    end_date = Column(DateTime)
    status = Column(String)
    comment = Column(String)
    creator_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    created_by = relationship("UserModel", back_populates = "created_schedule")
    created_for_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    created_for = relationship("UserModel", back_populates="schedule")
```

Thank you all!

I tried to follow the suggestion of adding the foreign_key parameter but it still wouldn't work.